# SQL Server insert into

Tags: sql-server, insert-into

I am trying to insert into table1(colunm1, column2, column3) where column1 has multiple values.

ex:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (1419002, 1003,
         (select TaskTypeCode 
          from TaskTypeCodes 
          where TaskTypeID in (898,788,878,874)) )
```

Error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That is because you have a query where you need a column and that query returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Insert into..Select` syntax. Try this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 1419002, 1003, TaskTypeCode 
FROM TaskTypeCodes 
WHERE TaskTypeID in (898,788,878,874)
```

**Note:** Based on the error mentioned in question the above Insert query will insert more than one row. If you don't want that to happen then restrict the rows by adding `Where` clause(filter's) or `TOP`

Comment: i only had to remove extra ) at the end.